# throwing a halfling at an enemy

Tags: dnd-5e, throwing-things

I am playing as a 2ft 6in halfling bard college of swords. I want to have a goliath barbarian in our party throw me at an enemy with my dual scimitars drawn. I believe this can be done. I asked my dm, who wasn't sure but was willing to let me do some research and math to find out whether or not it will work.

So my question is: **can a goliath barbarian throw a 45lbs halfling into the air to attack an enemy?**

Comment: What do You think about the damage taken after you hit the target

Comment: I've updated the question to incude the system tag and marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!